# Gradient of Predictive Sparse Decomposition Cost function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, algorithms, optimization, convolution, partial-derivative

I am trying to minimize the following Cost function with respect to $X_m$.

$$
Energy = f(X) = \frac{1}{2}||I-\sum_{m=1}^{M}{C_m * X_m}||_2^2+\sum_{m=1}^{M}{||X_m-\phi(W_m * I)||_2^2}+\lambda|X|_1
$$

$$
X_{min}=\arg{ \min_x{f(X_m)}}
$$

with

$I:$ Input image (size: w x h)

$C_1 ... C_M:$ Decoder matrices (size: s x s)

$W_1 ... W_m:$ Encoder matrices (size: s x s)

$X_1 ... X_m:$ Sparse matrices (size: w+s-1 x h+s-1)

$C_m * X_m:$ The 2D convolution between $C_m$ and $X_m$. (In matlab: conv2(X,C,'valid'))

$W_m * I:$ The 2D convolution between $W_m$ and $I$. (In matlab: conv2(I,W,'full'))

$\phi(...):$ A (activation) function.

$||...||_2$: The L2-norm of a matrix.

$|...|_1:$ The L1-norm of a matrix.

I am trying to minimize the energy by using gradient descent algorithm:

$$
X_n=X_n-\nabla{f(X_n)} 
$$
where
$$
\nabla{f(X_n)} = C_n^{'} * (I-\sum_{m=1}^M C_m * X_m) + (X_n - \phi(W_n * I))
$$

with

$C_n^{'} * z:$ Convolution of the $180^{\circ}$ rotation of $C_n$ and z (In matlab: conv2(z,rot90(C,2),'full'))

When running the algorithm, the Energy doesn't minimize, but becomes only larger.
So I have 2 questions:

1. Is the gradient $\nabla{f(X_n)}$ of the energy function correct?
2. If the gradient is correct, what could be the problem that the energy doesn't minimize?

Comment: When you refer to the "$L_1$ norm of a matrix", do you mean the matrix norm induced by the $L_1$ norm on vectors?  Or do you just mean the sum of the absolute values of all the entries of the matrix.

Comment: What exactly is $X$?  How is it related to $X_1,\ldots,X_M$?  Shouldn't the input to $f$ be $X$ rather than $X_m$?

Comment: If $|X|_1$ means the sum of the absolute values of the entries of $X$, and if $X$ is some sort of concatenation of $X_1,\ldots,X_M$, then your cost function appears to separate, so that you have a separate optimization problem to solve for each $X_m$.  Is that correct?

Comment: Also note that your cost function isn't differentiable, so gradient descent won't work.

Comment: I believe the L1 norm is the induce matrix norm, but I am not a 100% sure.

Comment: I also think $|X|_1$ is $\sum_{m=1}^M{|X_m|_1}$. And $X_n \in X_1 ... X_M$. I calculate each $\nabla{f(X_n)}$ separately for $n \in 1 ... M$ and extract them separately from each $X_n$

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem lies in the border of the $X$ matrices. Because I do a full convolution (conv2(I,W,'full')), the $X$ matrices gets extra values from the convolution of zero-padded borders. 
So these borders and in specific the corners are dependent on fewer values in the image. This will contribute to larger gradient in these locations. The next iteration of the algorithm will try to rectify the update of the larger gradient. This results in some kind of oscillating behavior, increasing the energy rather than minimizing it.

A solution is changing the full convolution (conv2(I,W,'full')) into a valid convolution. Or by using a mask that reduces the impact of the border in the gradient.